# How to slow down posting using fb app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, cron

below is code of my app

```
        $response1 = $facebook->api('/294120253958442' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(5);
        $response2 = $facebook->api('/134804409926272' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(15);
        $response3 = $facebook->api('/202619002037' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
        $response4 = $facebook->api('/30410040944' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(6);
        $response5 = $facebook->api('/103561223082520' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(12);
```

i use this text with sleep timer but the problem is that some posts posted correctly but some posted immediately is there any perfect solution i have to make almost 123 api request and people will like and comment

So the question is that is there any way to let fb think that this is the normal request like i use sleep() but its not working correctly?

**note: I posted in my delected groups which i have to authorize to post and i just share the message which i want to share and its not a spam for further info please discuss before down vote thanks**

**Update**

below is my complete file code requested by my friend zerkms :)

```
        //making fb instance so that we can make api calls 
        require_once 'library/facebook.php';


            // Create our Application instance.
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId' => '1498*53*179__47',
              'secret' => 'Shhh... Its Seceret ;)',
              'cookie' => true,
            )); 


        //Prepare Wall post

            //connecting to mysql server and database than get the data 
                $con1 = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass;)");
                    if (!$con1)
                      {
                          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                          }


                mysql_select_db('db:P');

                //get last post info
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info:) LIMIT 1");
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $last_post = $row["last_post"];


                //get current post data 
                $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_data;) WHERE ID=$last_post  LIMIT 1");
                $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);


            //store table data in variable 
                $pmessage = $row1["message"];
                $plink = $row1["link"];
                $pname = $row1["name"];
                $pcaption = $row1["caption"];
                $pdescription = $row1["description"];
                $ppicture = $row1["picture"];
                $psource = $row1["source"];



            //long life access_token

                $long_life_token = "AAACITTZBnadsBAEKaetzal7w*pk0yBgeaRMZAit8iZAbhqyXVX*3IYCZB_changed_CtS3CrqBmLa9rPueABbZAmZClX1bwZDZD";

        //'picture' => $ppicture, 'source' => $psource include this latter

                    // compile the post for for user
                        $WallPost = array(
                            'access_token' => $long_life_token,
                            'message' => $pmessage,
                            'link' => $plink,
                            'name' => $pname,
                            'caption' => $pcaption,
                            'description' => $pdescription);  


        //making api call so that it can post on target wall
        $response = $facebook->api('/me' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost);

            $last_post_update = $last_post + 1;


    //update info table that post posted and next time we use next post for posting

        mysql_query("UPDATE info SET last_post=$last_post_update WHERE id='1'");

    //posting to groups wall with sleeping time support poster.xls
            $response1 = $facebook->api('/*941*0*395844*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(5);
            $response* = $facebook->api('/1348044099***7*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(15);
            $response3 = $facebook->api('/*0**1900*037' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response4 = $facebook->api('/30410040944' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response5 = $facebook->api('/1035*1**308*5*0' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response* = $facebook->api('/10*477739430335' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response7 = $facebook->api('/84**05480*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response8 = $facebook->api('/187350*04**08**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response9 = $facebook->api('/4*39***49744' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response10 = $facebook->api('/171***10**51' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response11 = $facebook->api('/1*9197031*7*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response1* = $facebook->api('/10054*45**870*5' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response13 = $facebook->api('/*45144714*93' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response14 = $facebook->api('/17343**7*717815' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response15 = $facebook->api('/111915**5557801' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response1* = $facebook->api('/133*0138**55770' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response17 = $facebook->api('/158797974189338' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response18 = $facebook->api('/*33*3078**94*08' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response19 = $facebook->api('/17410*979300***' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response*0 = $facebook->api('/157*481*430*458' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response*1 = $facebook->api('/1*3941*97*85181' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response** = $facebook->api('/1**089951*37501' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response*3 = $facebook->api('/315**3*451*59*4' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response*4 = $facebook->api('/***37895044*1*3' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response*5 = $facebook->api('/*3*054393471390' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response** = $facebook->api('/*440*1515*14491' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response*7 = $facebook->api('/184*7409490*430' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response*8 = $facebook->api('/1*8978959817*19' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response*9 = $facebook->api('/154*101413***7*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response30 = $facebook->api('/191***8809093*1' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response31 = $facebook->api('/137*33949*59387' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response3* = $facebook->api('/114474*38**4551' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response33 = $facebook->api('/133*715934049*1' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response34 = $facebook->api('/18**559*5137*33' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response35 = $facebook->api('/1879447979*4870' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response3* = $facebook->api('/1*1**94*7*37*85' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response37 = $facebook->api('/175**51*91144**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response38 = $facebook->api('/15900418749*799' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response39 = $facebook->api('/14487*885*10753' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response40 = $facebook->api('/***9**507048858' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response41 = $facebook->api('/*3*15140013*073' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response4* = $facebook->api('/*07474*4***9741' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response43 = $facebook->api('/151079718*78488' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response44 = $facebook->api('/117*81001*43907' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response45 = $facebook->api('/13*50*91*8*7594' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response4* = $facebook->api('/1781*9*7**3*845' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response47 = $facebook->api('/3*9089400705' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response48 = $facebook->api('/183898734978809' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response49 = $facebook->api('/133453830051738' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response50 = $facebook->api('/19*5151003*9374' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response51 = $facebook->api('/1750793**574*93' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response5* = $facebook->api('/*57554**4*7*93*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response53 = $facebook->api('/***3458071*0538' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response54 = $facebook->api('/13430*43000*404' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response55 = $facebook->api('/*77199875*3*5**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response5* = $facebook->api('/*54157594*37337' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response57 = $facebook->api('/*8449745159*533' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response58 = $facebook->api('/31487*4*1878045' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response59 = $facebook->api('/*4943*4117707*1' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response*0 = $facebook->api('/**7*8*5799989*5' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response*1 = $facebook->api('/18*530908489557' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response** = $facebook->api('/*877553*458415*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response*3 = $facebook->api('/*4844*48185*9*4' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response*4 = $facebook->api('/1*5504393489378' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response*5 = $facebook->api('/1*4**58035**757' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response** = $facebook->api('/*5403158795****' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response*7 = $facebook->api('/179015*454*7358' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response*8 = $facebook->api('/*4407333937' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response*9 = $facebook->api('/*14810578534008' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response70 = $facebook->api('/*3*148493075*99' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response71 = $facebook->api('/11193144**4495*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response7* = $facebook->api('/*375**97*9*3871' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response73 = $facebook->api('/185**997144*979' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response74 = $facebook->api('/1009957133*09**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response75 = $facebook->api('/15*71780480*458' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(15);
            $response7* = $facebook->api('/19*783437031189' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response77 = $facebook->api('/1**0985*0795384' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response78 = $facebook->api('/17173853951707*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(5);
            $response79 = $facebook->api('/1*1300933893455' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response80 = $facebook->api('/1110945*899***1' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(5);
            $response81 = $facebook->api('/18019587*0*1**4' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response8* = $facebook->api('/15*805038117037' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response83 = $facebook->api('/1300774704*5043' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response84 = $facebook->api('/1*753918398*981' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response85 = $facebook->api('/114514**1938101' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response8* = $facebook->api('/1*3744*9038*735' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response87 = $facebook->api('/10*10*97*150035' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response88 = $facebook->api('/190**98943**081' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response89 = $facebook->api('/17*47151*7***44' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response90 = $facebook->api('/***8744437*8715' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response91 = $facebook->api('/*****74477455*3' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response9* = $facebook->api('/194974453897*45' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response93 = $facebook->api('/1873*78579**744' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response94 = $facebook->api('/*7**3183*1*351*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response95 = $facebook->api('/**0808*579778*3' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response9* = $facebook->api('/*093457*5759184' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(5);
            $response97 = $facebook->api('/*49****71754051' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response98 = $facebook->api('/190487**0971307' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response99 = $facebook->api('/1445955*8938380' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response100 = $facebook->api('/*03438579**9*81' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response101 = $facebook->api('/1147779*8*091**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response10* = $facebook->api('/1*8*89**7*40*08' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response103 = $facebook->api('/*9*88*835781' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response104 = $facebook->api('/1870*49980*47**' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response105 = $facebook->api('/*358741898*8*48' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response10* = $facebook->api('/10***9409443*31' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response107 = $facebook->api('/34*5*104*03*917' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response108 = $facebook->api('/*45847838808173' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);
            $response109 = $facebook->api('/184*7780157*777' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response110 = $facebook->api('/1*83030*3*17*53' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(9);
            $response111 = $facebook->api('/*58**851758958*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response11* = $facebook->api('/3197*341805**18' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(10);
            $response113 = $facebook->api('/384*10481*0789*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response114 = $facebook->api('/180*4030*050*81' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response115 = $facebook->api('/31308*5754048*8' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(*);
            $response11* = $facebook->api('/311589115534*57' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(8);
            $response117 = $facebook->api('/*3313*5434*00*3' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response118 = $facebook->api('/17*455045804750' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response119 = $facebook->api('/*5**9457441*873' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response1*0 = $facebook->api('/15917*340789449' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response1*1 = $facebook->api('/*37933149591088' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(1*);
            $response1** = $facebook->api('/*15*93915**17*8' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(14);
            $response1*3 = $facebook->api('/317348881**8*35' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(13);
            $response1*4 = $facebook->api('/*77331**89**49*' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(11);
            $response1*5 = $facebook->api('/15*3939948*9*94' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost); sleep(7);

?>
```

Comment: Create some queue and run the worker periodically

Comment: i make file contain almost 123 api requests but the problem is that the sleep timer not work perfectly as its need to work

Comment: why do you think it is `sleep` issue? `sleep()` function works perfectly. How big delays do you need?

Comment: actually i checked first i try echo time than sleep() than echo time its work perfectly but when i try the above code its some times work perfectly and sometimes not 
i verify this with my friend who is in the same groups he get some notifications continuously and some after some time

Comment: so, if `sleep` works perfectly - what the question is about then?

Comment: no actually sleep works some times perfectly and sometimes i try to find any alternate or something which solve this sleep issue

Comment: it always works perfectly. The issue is not related to `sleep` at all. Could you please explain better with your **real** code (with sleeps), with your expectations and actual results? 35 minutes passed and still no details in the question

Comment: @zerkms my dear friend check i update my complete file code and done some necessary changes in this if you find something in this code which not need to be exposed please let me known so that secret will be secret :)

Comment: for such small sleep delays it is expected, because facebook doesn't guarantee anything to appear immediately on the pages, due to their cache

Comment: @zerkms can you please more clear your last comment

Comment: what you see as a result of execution of your script is **expected** facebook behaviour, because FB doesn't guarantee the feed to appear *immediately* after your API call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9656/discussion-between-abdullah-adam-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 0):

Try using functions instead:  *Not tested*

```
function r1(){
    $response1 = $facebook->api('/294120253958442'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
function r2(){
    $response2 = $facebook->api('/134804409926272'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
function r3(){
    $response3 = $facebook->api('/202619002037'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost); 
}
function r4(){
    $response4 = $facebook->api('/30410040944'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost); 
}
function r5(){
    $response5 = $facebook->api('/103561223082520'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
r1();sleep(5);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";  // time stamps should echo 5 seconds apart.
r2();sleep(5);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
r3();sleep(5);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
r4();sleep(5);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
r5();sleep(5);
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
```

Alternatively if sleep is returning null after sleep has occurred "windows server" you can set up a timer to fire the functions. Idle time is spent looping, not the best way to go.

```
function r1(){
    $response1 = $facebook->api('/294120253958442'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
function r2(){
    $response2 = $facebook->api('/134804409926272'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
function r3(){
    $response3 = $facebook->api('/202619002037'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
function r4(){
    $response4 = $facebook->api('/30410040944'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost); 
}
function r5(){
    $response5 = $facebook->api('/103561223082520'.'/feed','POST',$WallPost);
}
$i=1;
function timer(){
    $now = time();
    while ($now + 5 > time()) {
        // do nothing
    }
    if($i<5){
        $i++;r'.$i.'(); echo 'posted'.date('h:i:s') . "\n"; timer();
    }else{
        $i=1; echo 'starting over'; timer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it would change anything?!

Comment: i suggest this because php sleep can be interupted by signals and will always continue loading as sleep is in que.

wraping your request will prevent it from executing while the sleep's are qued.

MORE HELP HERE http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: @Shawn E Carter: "wraping your request will prevent it from executing while the sleep's are qued" --- nope, you're wrong

Comment: its shows this error


"Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object in mysite/script1c.php on line 78"

Comment: @Shawn E Carter: it works, but it wouldn't change anything in comparison to the same calls separated by sleeps. The wrapping with function adds **NOTHING** special

Comment: @Abdullah Adam: of course - that's because `$facebook` is not defined within functions. But anyway - this solution is incorrect, just because it changes nothing

Comment: php will see the api request as just string, thus running it as sleep is in que,  wrapping in a function, the request loads as a function and is executed only when called.  How is this not logical?

Comment: @Shawn E Carter: it's not logical, because what you say is just a nonsense. There is **no difference** how php calls the code. No difference at all. There is no any "queue"

Comment: oh please no down vote at least care the persons effort and please remove down vote thanks

Comment: @abdullah  seeing your code i would create an array of your ids, then loop them calling a funtion like postid(groupid);sleep(7); where function itself includes the post request.

Comment: thank you so much voted up :)
i got the solution from @zerkms after a long discussion